How to do multi-class and for several target variables with neural network?
I would like to do classification using Neural Network. I have several features that are mostly categorical and multiple targets (15 targets) that are also categorical. each feature and target variable has more than 2 classes so it is not a binary classification and not a single target problem. What is a suitable model for my problem?
Previously I was using the following method but not sure how suitable is it becuase it is using KerasRegressor and mse as the loss.
def create_model(hidden_layers=1, units=32, activation='relu'):
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
    for _ in range(hidden_layers):
        model.add(layers.Dense(units, activation=activation))
    model.add(layers.Dense(Y_train.shape[1]))  # Output layer
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    return model
# Wrap the model using KerasRegressor
nn_model = KerasRegressor(model=create_model, verbose=0)

As a second trial, I was using KerassClassifier but I am getting error as below:
    def create_model(hidden_layers=1, units=32, activation='relu'):
        inputs = layers.Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],))
        shared_layers = inputs
        for _ in range(hidden_layers):
            shared_layers = layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)(shared_layers)

        output_heads = []
        for output_dim in Y_train.shape[2:]:
            output_head = layers.Dense(output_dim, activation='softmax', name=f'output_{len(output_heads)}')(shared_layers)
            output_heads.append(output_head)

        model = models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output_heads)
        losses = ['categorical_crossentropy'] * len(output_heads)
        metrics = ['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()]
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=losses, metrics=metrics)
        return model


 # Use KerasClassifier instead of KerasRegressor for multi-class classification
    nn_model = KerasClassifier(model=create_model, verbose=0)

ValueError: Detected a Keras model input of size 1, but  has 1083 outputs

This is multi-label classification, it is recommended to employ
binary_crossentropy as the loss function. Additionally, the output layer
should utilize a sigmoid activation function and have a number of neurons
equivalent to the number of classes. For this specific task, keras_Classifier
is the appropriate model choice.
